# Routing with regex condition in Rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, rest

In my routes.rb file, I've defined these routes:

```
  map.with_options(:controller => "review") do |review|
    review.review_index    "/review/:page", :action => "index", :defaults => {:page => nil}, :requirements => {:page => /[0-9]./}
    review.review_provider "/review/:category_name/:page", :action => "provider", :defaults => {:page => nil}
  end
```

However, it only match with the second routes.
For example,

```
/review/1
```

must match with first rule but in fact it is matched with the second rule.

How can I config it so that:

```
/review/1 will match with the first rule
/review/a_category/1 will  match with the second rule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression in your first route is bad.  Period matches any single character.

`/[0-9]/` means "any number, followed by any other single character".

So, that would match `/review/1a`, `/review/70`, `/review/7?`, etc,

If you want to match one or more digits, change your regular expression to: `/[0-9]+/`

Comment: it's so embarassed! How can I not pay attention to such error. Thank you for pointing out messick